# i have problem in firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

error occur in second argument of signInWithPhoneNumber() and i am not able to fix this problem, in there is three method i used for send otp, verify otp and last on for captcha

```
methods:{
 sendOTP(e){
   e.preventDefault();
     if(this.phoneNo.length!=10){
         alert('Invalid No.');
     }else{
         let countryCode="+91"
         let phoneNumber=countryCode+ this.phoneNo
         let appVerifier=window.recaptchaVerifier

         firebase.default.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
         .then(function (confirmationResult){
           console.log(confirmationResult);
             window.confirmationResult=confirmationResult;
             alert('SMS sent')
         }).catch(function(err){
           console.log(err);
             alert('SMS not sent')
         });

     }
 },
```

this method for verify OTP using firebase

```
verifyOTP(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
    if(this.phoneNo.length!=10||this.otp.length!=6){
        alert('Invalid format')
    }
    else{
        let vm=this
        let code=this.otp
         //var user
        window.confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(function (result){
            console.log(result);
            var user = user.result
            vm.$router.push({path:'/home'})
        })
    }
},
```

here i initial the captcha method

```
initReCaptcha(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      //let vm = this
      window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
        'size': 'invisible',
        'callback': function() {
          // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
          // ...
        },
        'expired-callback': function() {
          // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
          // ...
        }
      });
      //
      this.appVerifier =  window.recaptchaVerifier
    },1000)
  },
```

here i created captcha

```
created(){
  this.initReCaptcha()
}
```

Comment: all of them is inside method

Comment: OT: you get no error with `e.preventDefault()`? in Vue you do `event.preventDefault()` as your `e` is not an event but what you are passing into the function, better yet is to do it on the button bind, like `@click.prevent="myFunction()"`

Comment: no error occur when i e.preventDefault()

Comment: Error: signInWithPhoneNumber failed: Second argument "applicationVerifier" must be an implementation of firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier

Comment: @puf can u help to fix this problem