# Implementation of firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I'm stuck on implementation of ApplicationVerifier of firebase phone number authentication and i posted the problem but no one can answer correctly [i have problem in firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205884/i-have-problem-in-firebase-auth-applicationverifier)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i have problem in firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205884/i-have-problem-in-firebase-auth-applicationverifier)

Comment: yes @tomerpacific